# Parsing a json-array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, get

I'm trying to find a way to parse a javascript object in order to display it into my website. I'm kinda confused because I'm performing a GET request on a php page and it gives me a strange type of JSON. I tried to parse this object like a normal JSON, but it don't work. I leave you a snippet the object.

```
{
"0": {
    "Msg KEY": "123456789",
    "Msg ID": "A00001",
    "Msg Author": "sandro",
    "Msg Text": "Text #0"
},
"1": {
    "Msg KEY": "123456789",
    "Msg ID": "A00002",
    "Msg Author": "sandro",
    "Msg Text": "Text #1"
},
"2": {
    "Msg KEY": "123456789",
    "Msg ID": "A00003",
    "Msg Author": "sandro",
    "Msg Text": "Text #2"
},
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the code provided in your snippet is the entire code, then you have a JSON syntax error on the second to last line.

JSON isn't too fond of trailing comma's.

```
    },   <----
}
```

After removing that, it should happily go through `JSON.parse( string_here_please );`

```js
var rawstring = `{
    "0": {
        "Msg KEY": "123456789",
        "Msg ID": "A00001",
        "Msg Author": "sandro",
        "Msg Text": "Text #0"
    },
    "1": {
        "Msg KEY": "123456789",
        "Msg ID": "A00002",
        "Msg Author": "sandro",
        "Msg Text": "Text #1"
    },
    "2": {
        "Msg KEY": "123456789",
        "Msg ID": "A00003",
        "Msg Author": "sandro",
        "Msg Text": "Text #2"
    }
}`;

var myjson = JSON.parse( rawstring );
console.log( "Parsed JSON:" );
console.log( myjson );
console.log( "Example Entry:" );
console.log( myjson["0"] );
```

You could always use a lint to see if your JSON string is valid, for example this one;
https://jsonlint.com/